# Border collapse not working on nested table

Tags: html, css

Here's what I get, border-collapse not working:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
what I mean by border-collapse not working is that you can clearly see that the inner table has a double border, which does not look good.

Simplified version of the code:

```
<style>
table, tr, td
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Content inner</td>
                <td>Content inner</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the desired result? `border-collapse` seems to be working fine.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry I answered before but comment was not posted. Yes I am using tables, it's complicated but I cannot avoid it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a combination of `border-left` and `border-top` for the cells and a border on all sides except the left on the table itself. Then you'd use the `:first-child` pseudo-selector to get rid of the extra `border-top` for cells in the first row.

`border-collapse` has a different effect than what I think you're expecting (it's not exactly intuitive I know). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse for examples of what `border-collapse` actually does.

For an example of the above-mentioned technique see the .table-bordered class in Twitter Bootstrap. I tried to copy and paste the code from there but it's a bit spread out and the source is in LESS so it's probably better to just go to the Bootstrap homepage if you want to check it out. (The example I posted here earlier didn't work quite right.)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that maybe I wasn't using border-collapse for the right thing. However I thought of your solution, but when there are more than one inner row, it will start to make complicated css as there will be some for the first inner rows, the middle inner rows and the last inner row, plus all the left borders to remove on the first td and right borders on the last td. If there is another simpler solution, that would be nice, if not, I'll accept your solution as is.

Comment: I know.. company needs a layout like this, with a few outer rows, then a few inner rows, than a few more outer, etc.. I think I will forget about it